# Add an integer to the start of an existing array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm given an array of `int` and I need to return a new array with the number 3 added to the start of the array.

So if the array is `MyArray[1,2,3]` I need to create new array that says `[3,1,2,3]`.

I'm not sure how I am supposed to do this without using **ArrayList**. I need to do it with just loops.

Comment: Java arrays are of a fixed length, hence we normally use ArrayList for this sort of thing, Are you allowed to create a new array?

Comment: Use two arrays if its a must, one with a size+1 to another and add the elements as your problem statement states.

Comment: Yea. I'm supposed to create a new array that copies over the elements from the existing array. So in the post the existing array would be MyArray and I need to make a new array that copies what MyArray has, but with just a 3 in the front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public int[] insert(int[] src, int value)
{
    int[] dest = new int[src.length + 1];
    dest[0] = value;
    for (int i=0; i<src.length; i++)
    {
        dest[i+1] = src[i];
    }
    return dest;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
int[] newArray = insert(MyArray, 3);
```

This is the basic idea. You'll need to put this into a class, add error checking (eg. what happens if `src` is `null`), etc.

Comment: Hey this is awesome, thank you! So the only problem is I'm confined to what I can do since I'm doing this on a practice website (I tried it in eclipse and it works perfect). The method i'm supposed to add it into starts with this 

`int[] prepend5(int[] nums) `

 and I can't change it since it's a practice problem. Is there a way to add the 3 to the begging still?

Comment: The general idea should be transportable to your practice website. Feel free to mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: yeah it sort of works. I need to use this code in a method `int[] prepend5(int[] nums)` Without the insert it only returns 0 at the start of the array.

Comment: Take the body of `insert()` and use it within `prepend5()`. Instead of `value`, simply use a hard-coded `3`. Use `nums` instead of `src`.

Comment: @dave I'm dumb. I didn't realize I could just hardcode the 3 instead of Value. This makes a lot of sense now. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps I shouldn't have generalised my answer to accept any value (as opposed to hard-coding a 3).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an explicit loop here, because you can presumably use [`System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPost, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-). First, decide how you want to handle `null` input for your array (returning a new one element array is what I would expect). Otherwise, create a new array with room for one more element. Set the first value, then copy everything at an offset of 1. Finally, return the new array. Like,

```
public static int[] insertValue(int[] src, int value) {
    if (src == null) {
        return new int[] { value };
    }
    int[] dest = new int[src.length + 1];
    dest[0] = value;
    System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 1, src.length);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: *First, decide how you want to handle null input for your array (returning a new one element array is what I would expect).* I'd much sooner let it throw a NPE. It's the most natural and logical course of action IMO.

Comment: @shmosel Then you could simply not use the `if` (different strokes for different folks).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.arrayCopy()`

```
public int[] insert(int[] src, int value) {
        int[] dest = new int[src.length + 1];
        dest[0] = value;
        System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 1, src.length);
        return dest;
    }
```

Comment: You can use `arrayCopy()` but the OP is required to use a loop.